# What is Math in Java?

Tags: java, class

When I want to use the mathematical methods in Java like `abs` `acos` I have to put it like this: `Math.abs(int a)`, `Math.acos(double a)`.

But what does it really mean?

Is `Math` the name of the class or some object? How does it work?

Comment: `Math` is `class` which have `static` methods like `abs` etc.

Comment: `Math` is name of class placed in `java.lang` package which is why we don't need to import it and can use in our code directly (just like any other classes from that package, like for `String`, `Integer`).

That is *utility* class, which has only `static` methods for mathematical expressions. Because methods are static we invoke them on class itself like `Math.abs(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

Math class has static methods. So you can invoke it like:

```
int absolute = Math.abs(-123);
// absolute now has +123
```

A static method can be invoked without creating an instance of a class.

Comment: or use static import: `import java.lang.Math.abs;` and invoke `abs(int a)` directly in your code as you would do with a static method inside the same class. But to keep in mind, this may confuse the devs and only use if your code is getting lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

> The class Math contains methods for performing basic numeric
>   operations such as the elementary exponential, logarithm, square root,
>   and trigonometric functions.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html